# IIS Worker Process busy using Hangfire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, hangfire

I'm using Hangfire in my MVC webapp. I configured it this way:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
         .UseMongoStorage(mongoConnectionString, mongoDatabaseName);

app.UseHangfireServer();
```

When I run the application I see `IIS Worker Process` takes constantly almost 40% CPU.

Removing it brings the application to works normally.

What's wrong?

Comment: What version of Hangfire.Mongo package are you using?

Comment: I'm using `Hangfire MongoDB Storage 0.2.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hangfire.Mongo* since version 0.2.2 uses a new version of the *mongocsharpdriver* package that migrated to async API when talking with Mongo. Hangfire still uses synchronous methods, and looks like there is an error in "sync over async" wrapper.

One user reported that after setting the following options everything is fine.

```
CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
```

However, the fix isn't available currently, and another option is to downgrade the Hangfire.Mongo package to the previous version. Please see the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/Hangfire.Mongo/issues/10).